# C++ / Rcpp - Changing a specific character in a string

Tags: c++, r, string, replace, rcpp

I'm new in C and C++, so I´m using Rcpp library in Rstudio to change the character 'S' to 'Z' when it is between vowels.
I'm trying to use the iterator i with the .at function t change it for 'Z', but that line seems to be wrong.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

//cc represents the current_character
#define cc   *i

string vowels = "AEIOU";

/* Define .begin .end functions
 */

i = word.begin();
  while(i != word.end()){
    if( cc == 'S' && is(vowels,pc) && is(vowels,nc) ) {

      // the line below seems to e wrong
      word.at(i) == 'Z';

      i += 1;
    } else {
        i += 1;
    }
   }
```

Comment: That's not yet a callable function.

Comment: at least in C++, `at(size_t pos)` requires an argument of type `size_t`, not an iterator. Further, are you sure about the `==` if you want to assign something?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of potential errors in this program.

First as @StephanLechner points out you might not mean '==' in

word.at(i) == 'Z';

The macro 'cc' is incredible dangerous, at least it needs a () but better yet don't use it.

You have a potential "off by one" error in the loop.

```
is(vowels,nc)
```

might use one beyond the end of the word.

```
is(vowels,nc)
```

nc is what? if nc is another macro it hides the true value.